# How to set the Initial Value for a Property of a Block (Enterprise Architect)

Tags: enterprise-architect

## Problem Statement

I have a Block called "Block1". In the Block I have inserted a standard Property type with name "est_Mass". I want to define the Initial Value of using a script (which pulls the number from somewhere else). However I couldn't find a way to do so.

My pseudocode was as follows

```
define theBlock as EA.Element;
theBlock = Repository.GetTreeSelectedObject();
someValue = 49;
numOfElements = theBlock.Elements.Count;
counter = 0;
while (counter < numOfElements) {
    if (theBlock.Elements.GetAt(counter).Name = "est_Mass"){
    //how to set the "Initial" value for this property to someValue?
    }
    counter = counter + 1;
}
```

[image: image of property tab in Properties window]

[image: image of block diagram with properties]

[image: picture of block with properties]

## Solution with CustomProperties

**Updated based on the provided answers and re-iterated here in JavaScript for completeness**

I've written a script that updates the 'default' value using the CustomProperties class.

### Script

```js
var theBlock as EA.Element;
var eaPart as EA.Element;

var numOfElements;
var numOfCustomProperties;
var someValue = 49;

let counter = 0;
let customPropCounter = 0;

theBlock = Repository.GetTreeSelectedObject();
numOfElements = theBlock.Elements.Count;

//loop through elements that are owned by the Block
loop:
while (counter < numOfElements){
    if (theBlock.Elements.GetAt(counter).Name === "est_Mass"){
        
        eaPart = theBlock.Elements.GetAt(counter);
        numOfCustomProperties = eaPart.CustomProperties.Count;
        
        //loop through custom properties of the desired part
        while (customPropCounter < numOfCustomProperties) {
            if (eaPart.CustomProperties.GetAt(customPropCounter).Name === "default") {
                Session.Output( `***\n Before assignment ${eaPart.CustomProperties.GetAt(customPropCounter).Name} \
                                custom property of ${theBlock.Elements.GetAt(counter).Name} \
                                is ${eaPart.CustomProperties.GetAt(customPropCounter).Value} \n***`);
                //assign new value
                eaPart.CustomProperties.GetAt(customPropCounter).Value = someValue;
                //update the part that owns the custom propert
                eaPart.Update();
                Session.Output( `***\n After assignment ${eaPart.CustomProperties.GetAt(customPropCounter).Name} \
                                custom property of ${theBlock.Elements.GetAt(counter).Name} \
                                is ${eaPart.CustomProperties.GetAt(customPropCounter).Value} \n***`);
                //let's get outta here
                break loop;
            }
            customPropCounter = customPropCounter + 1;
        }
    }   
    counter = counter + 1;
}
```

### Output

```
***
 Before assignment default custom property of est_Mass is 0 
***
***
 After assignment default custom property of est_Mass is 49 
***
```

Close the diagram that shows the block and reopen it. The value for the "est_Mass" is now 49

Comment: Could you please show how the elements are defined in the browser?

Comment: added a picture. looks like "est_Mass: kg". "kg" is my value type used to 'type' the property (not to be confused with stereotyping).

Comment: You are using SysML?

Comment: There is no `default` column in t_xref

Comment: Have you tried the `EA.Element.CustomProperties` collection. You might be able to edit them that way (so no more need to use the `Execute` backdoor)

Comment: Your update query is completely wrong. You are trying to set a column `t_xref.default` that doesn't exist with the xml string returned by SQLQuery. That xml string was never in the database. You need to update`t_xref.Description` with a value like it contains now, only with `@VALU` updated.

Comment: Geert, I've tried to use CustomProperties to make the update but for some reason it didn't stick. I've updated the original post to include the script and output

Comment: Did you remember to call `update()` after changing the custom property?

Comment: I updated the SQL script to update t_xref.Description instead of t_xref.default and I no long have the error pop out. However the value on the property doesn't actually get updated. Anything related to the different xrefid (see my output in the original post)?

Comment: See my updated answer instead!

Comment: @Greet when I change my script from `eaPart.CustomProperties.GetAt(customPropCounter).Update;` to `eaPart.CustomProperties.GetAt(customPropCounter).Update();` I get the error `eaPart.CustomProperties.GetAt(...).Update is not a function`

Comment: I think you need to call `Update()` on the `eaPart` after updating the value of he custom property. PS. My name is Gee**r**t, not Greet. If you use the proposed name when typing @, you can't misspell, and I get a ping so I know you replied.

Comment: @GeertBellekens thanks for the tip and apologies for the naming kerfuffle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These properties are stored in the [`EA.Element.CustomProperties`](https://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.2/automation/customproperties.html) collection

You can iterate over them and update their `Value`.

Remember to call `Update()` on the `EA.Element` that owns the `CustomProperties` to make sure your changes are saved.

In vbscript that would be something like

```
dim customProperty as EA._CustomProperty
'loop custom properties to find the one we need
for each customProperty in eaPart.CustomProperties
    if customProperty.Name = "Max_Mass" then
        customProperty.Value = "50"
        exit for 'found it, no need to continue
    end if
next
'remember to update the element to save changes
eaPart.Update
```

Reload the diagram you are looking at to make sure the changes in the database are also reflected on the diagram. Diagram keep data in memory and are not always notified when elements are changed by the API.

Comment: I guess that's it. I just forgot about looking into the API :-/

Comment: @qwerty_so Been there, done that :). Sometimes you're that deep into the rabbit hole you don't even realize there's other (cleaner) solutions as well.

Comment: Huh. Now trying to Update a customproperty and EA croaks that there is no update??

Comment: Ah! EAUI! You have to call sub-element.update

Comment: @qwerty_so Yep, update the Element instead

Comment: Just figured that out :-) And I see (I should learn to read) that you actually wrote it in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Important**: Please refer to Geert's answer. This one is the way "behind the scenes" and should be avoided in normal cases. I leave it here - just in case.

---

I'm not familiar with Javascript, so I can only answer using an abstract language. Also I don't have SysML but assuming they reference the initial value of a property, this should get you going:

```
sub = theBlock.Elements.GetAt(counter)
query = "SELECT xrefid, description FROM t_xref WHERE client = '" + sub.elementGuid m+ "' AND name = 'CustomProperties'"
res = repository.SQLQuery(query)
```

You need to parse the XML result which contains 0..n rows; first column with a GUID and the 2nd with the description.One of them looks like

```
 @PROP=@NAME=default@ENDNAME;@TYPE=String@ENDTYPE;@VALU=initial@ENDVALU;@PRMT=@ENDPRMT;@ENDPROP;@PROP=@NAME=isReference@ENDNAME;@TYPE=boolean@ENDTYPE;@VALU=0@ENDVALU;@PRMT=@ENDPRMT;@ENDPROP;
```

Yes, this is Sparxian coding :-(

This is were you get the initial in between `@VALU=...@ENDVALU`.

In 13.5 that is defined here:

[image]

Now if you need to alter that it can be done like this

```
repository.execute("UPDATE t_xref SET default='<the modfied desc>' WHERE xrefid='<theGuid>'")
```

This is an undocumented and unsupported operation which however is working since EA exists and the Sparxians will not block it since all their consultants are using it. You just don't get support if for that. Especially not when you clobber your DB by using it. So: backup please and test in the sandbox!

`<the modfied desc>` must be the same string as the description you retrieved except for the `@VALU=...@ENDVALU` part where you need to string-substitue the `...`. `<theGuid>` is the one retrieved for the according row.

(Since I could not test it for JS please come back with issues if you run into some - likely...)

---

As a sample: the query could have returned

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<EADATA version="1.0" exporter="Enterprise Architect">
<Dataset_0><Data><Row><xrefid>{91790A06-2119-411d-8308-FCFC9D7EE3E5}</xrefid><description>@PROP=@NAME=isReference@ENDNAME;@TYPE=boolean@ENDTYPE;@VALU=0@ENDVALU;@PRMT=@ENDPRMT;@ENDPROP;@PROP=@NAME=default@ENDNAME;@TYPE=String@ENDTYPE;@VALU=0@ENDVALU;@PRMT=@ENDPRMT;@ENDPROP;</description></Row></Data></Dataset_0></EADATA>
```

So the `description` column contains

```
@PROP=@NAME=isReference@ENDNAME;@TYPE=boolean@ENDTYPE;@VALU=0@ENDVALU;@PRMT=@ENDPRMT;@ENDPROP;@PROP=@NAME=default@ENDNAME;@TYPE=String@ENDTYPE;@VALU=0@ENDVALU;@PRMT=@ENDPRMT;@ENDPROP;
```

and the guid is `{91790A06-2119-411d-8308-FCFC9D7EE3E5}`

In order to change the default from `0` to `49` you need to issue the following SQL:

```
UPDATE t_xref SET description = '@PROP=@NAME=isReference@ENDNAME;@TYPE=boolean@ENDTYPE;@VALU=0@ENDVALU;@PRMT=@ENDPRMT;@ENDPROP;@PROP=@NAME=default@ENDNAME;@TYPE=String@ENDTYPE;@VALU=49@ENDVALU;@PRMT=@ENDPRMT;@ENDPROP;' WHERE xrefid='{91790A06-2119-411d-8308-FCFC9D7EE3E5}'
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed the `res` string as you mentioned, just changing the `@VALU=0@ENDVALU` part of the res string to `@VALU=49@ENDVALU` but now I'm getting a DAO.Database [0x00000bf5] "Data is insufficient, expecting 1" (the wording is a translation from Chinese to English but you should be able to get the point). Any suggestions?

Comment: I updated the original post that hopefully you can help check.

Comment: At which position do you get the error? Can you debug print the SQL that causes the error? What database are you using?

Comment: I've updated the original post with hopefully some helpful console output. I'm not familiar with SQL so the database you referred to should be the local repository. I didn't set up any databases here.

Comment: Thanks @qwerty_so for the tips. Based on your input I was able to run the SQL based script to make the change. Two questions: First, the one used in the query string I get but then why does the returned string have a different GUID? Secondly, can you point me in the direction of documentation pertaining to the use of SQL in searching EA repository?

Comment: The returned GUID is the PK of t_xref. For EA internals: http://liquit.biz/brain/books.html (Inside)